# public type modifiers for interface

Tags: c#, interface

When a class implements an interface, the type modifiers for the interface members should be public. Why is there such a restriction?

Comment: mempublic? also: by "type modifiers", do you mean "accessibility modifiers"?

Comment: The interface members are implicitly public.  Not the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

An interface defines how other objects will communicate with objects of the type that implements that interface; Since other objects can only interact with the public properties and methods of other types, the interface must define those properties and methods as public.

Comment: except they don't need to be public... they can be explicit

Comment: While technically I agree, I do consider an explicit interface to still define a public contract of a type; The fact that a type implements that interface is part of its public definition, and getting at those interface members is therefore both easy and guaranteed/required.  Private defines what is encapsulated and hidden by a type, which an interface really isn't part of.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of implementing an interface method; the first is *implicit* implementation - which assumes the public API is exposing the interface methods, and is what you are no-doubt seeing.

However, you can also use *explicit* implementation:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose() {
    // clean up
}
```

is a trivial example; this is private, yet satisfies the interface. An explicit implementation always takes precedence over a like-named method on the public API.

In fact, explicit implementation is often *necessary*, for example to implement `IEnumerable<T>` - since there are two conflicting `GetEnumerator()` methods; the following is common:

```
// public API will be used for implicit IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { ... do work ... }
// explicit implementation of IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
```

So: if you don't want public members; use explicit implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say an Interface can have Private members. When a class inherits the interface, the class will never be able to access the private member. The class will never be able to implement the private member and the program will never get compiled.