# Access internal interfaces inside owner class

Tags: c#

I have an internal interface. Usually I use public interfaces but this time I am keeping alot of things internal.

Now the question is when I am in a public class that implements an internal interface which futhermore containers a internal member why cant I access interface member without casting (explicit implementation)? I am inside the "owner" class, the class that implements the interface, completely inside, I should have all rights, right?

I wouldnt mind if I only use that casting once in code but thats not the case. I have such constellation 10 times in code. Its a bit annoying.

Am I missing something? Like I said I dont work with internal interfaces normally.

Before you start downvoting or posting how this question is a duplicate just drop a comment and I will remove it.

Here is code:

```
internal class Poco
{
    public string Str
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

internal interface ITest1
{
    Poco Obj
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Foo : ITest1
{
    // Not working
    Poco Obj
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, the convention for declaring an interfaces would mean you should name it `IKey`, or maybe even `IKeyable`.

Comment: Access modifier to Obj in Foo is missin. It's private by default

Comment: No access modifier works here. Try it out.

Comment: in order to implement interface implicitly method/property must be public non-static [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx)

Comment: @dh. the example works if you implement explicitly. there you go you learned something new too :) :)

Comment: Yeah, because you have a explicit implementation of an internal property in an internal interface, so it can't be used outside the assembly.

Comment: this is just fine and corresponds to a c# specification completelly see [Explicit Interface Implementation (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx)

Comment: I dont want it to be used outside. That is why i have internal interface in the first place. my question is why is explicit implementation needed? I am trying to understand the background. I have 10 casts because of explicit implementation. I dont want to have 10.

Comment: in your case you don't need explicit interface implementation. you need to provide a public interface defining public functionality for use outside the assembly and make your class internal and use it directly or with your interface. if I understand all your requirements properly.

Comment: class shall be accessable from outside, interface shall only stay inside

Comment: then I would go with answer from Eli Arbel just use a private backing field for a property from ITest1 interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the `internal` acces modfifier with **explicit implementation** of an interface.

The fact that the interface is `internal` has nothing to do with its visibility inside the implementing class. It only restricts visisbility to the local assembly.

The explicit implementation allows for name-clashes:

```
interface IKey1 { int ID { ... } }
interface IKey2 { int ID { ... } }

class MyOwnerClass : IKey1, IKey2  // requires explicit imp
{
  int IKey1.ID  {  ....  }
  int IKey2.ID  {  ....  }

  // the only way to access this:
  void Foo() 
  { 
     int i1 = ((IKey1)this).ID; 

     IKey2 ik2 = this;
     int i2 = ik2.ID; 

     int i3 = ID; // error, otherwise: which one
  }
}
```

Your core question: How to acces an interface member without casting. In this example any reference to `this.ID` would be ambiguous.

And implicit implementation of intefaces with conflicting members is not allowed.

> why is `private iKey.ID` not working.

The compiler controls visisbility here, and makes it even more hidden than 'private'. This is similar to why you can't use `public` inside `interface IA { ... }`

---

### After the Edit

Completely different situation:

```
internal class Poco { ... }     // this 'internal' is a problem 
internal interface ITest1       // this isn't
{ 
  Poco Obj  {  }                // Poco is an internal type
}

public class Foo : ITest1
{
    // Not working
    Poco Obj  { ... }          // property _and_ type need to be public
}
```

You are trying to have a public property on a public class but of an internal type.
Look at it from *outside* the assembly:

```
 Foo f = ...;   // OK, Foo is a public Type
 f.Obj = ...;   // but we don't know the Type of Obj here
```

Comment: I dont have two ID properties. I have a public class that implements internal interface and compiler forces me to use explicit implementation but why? int ID { get; set } is not working but int iKey.ID { get; set; } works. So why explict way when using internal interfaces?

Comment: You drew a wrong conclusion somewhere. A `public class` can implicitly implement an `internal interface`. No problem there.

Comment: Tip: write up a small, self contained project demonstrating your issue. Complete code should be less than 20 lines and postable.

Comment: I edited my question. The class poco is internal. Its inside the internal interface. Owner is public though.

Comment: The `internal class Poco` is the source of most problems here.

Comment: Poco must be internal. What can I do?

Comment: Why must `Poco` be internal?

Comment: Then Foo must be `internal` too. Or wrap `Poco` in a public interface `IPoco`.

Comment: The foo must stay public, the poco must stay internal. It works with explicit implementation though for whatever reason. try it out

Comment: Yes, it compiles but you can't use `ITest1` in another assembly so it doesn't lead to a conflict. You just can't use Obj.

Comment: I dont want to use obj outside. My question is why do i need explicit way to this constellation.

Comment: How could I reduce those 10 castings then?

Comment: You can't. You have an exceptional config where explicit is required and explicit requires the cast. You can use a private helper method/property to ease the pain a little.

Answer (score 2):

You can have an internal (or even a private) property as well as an explicit interface implementation that exposes it:

```
public class Foo : ITest1
{
    internal Poco Obj { get; set; }

    Poco ITest1.Obj { get { return Obj; } set { Obj = value; } }
}
```

That is the recommended way of "changing" interface member visibility. Many .NET classes use this technique to convert interface members to `protected virtual` members.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way explicit interfaces are defined in the specification.

The "explicit" part means "I will tell the code when to treat that object as an interface", so unless you tell the code (by casting), it won't see the interface's methods / properties. This is incredibly useful if you have two interfaces that have a method with the same name.

You can have an internal Interface, but you won't be able to use it for classes that are public (see [this post](http://ericlippert.com/2012/11/13/why-is-deriving-a-public-class-from-an-internal-class-illegal/) for some of the reasoning).

Here is an example of a valid implementation:

```
internal interface IKeyable
{
  int ID {get; set;}
}

internal class MyClass: IKeyable
{
  public int ID  { get; set; }
}
```

---

About the question edit:

There are several thing that won't work with that scenario:

1. The `Obj` property of the `Foo` class is (by default) private, so it won't be accessible outside the class, with or without the interface.
2. Because **all** member defined in an interface **must** be accessible from outside the class the `Obj` is not considered a suitable candidate for the implementation of the `ITest1` interface.
3. While `Foo` is public, `Poco` is internal, meaning that even if the user (from outside the assembly will be able to access the class, he won't be able to access the property, and that does not make sense.

If you want to expose a internal class to the world (exposing it's data, for example, but not it's internal nitty-gritty), you can create a public access interface, or create a public access class that will know to transform to/from your class.

So you can do:

```
public interface IPoco { 
   string Title {get; } //restring writing, for example
}

internal class Poco : IPoco
{
   public string Title {get; set; } //read/write access within the assembly
}

public class Foo 
{
   public IPoco MyPoco {get; set;}
}
```

or

```
public class PocoAccessor
{
   public string Title {get; private set;}  
   internal static PocoAccessor ToPocoAccessor(Poco source)
   {
      return new PocoAccessor { Title = source.Title}
   }
}

public class Foo 
{
   public PocoAccessor MyPoco {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: +1 for "This is incredibly useful if you have two interfaces that have a method with the same name." - no more explanation required

Comment: so what are you trying to achieve? make a property invisible outside the assembly and implement an internal interface? then why do you need that interface if you want to access it directly? why don't you use a public interface to allow access from outside the assembly to public functionality? aren't you trying to merge different responsibilities within one type?

Comment: @devhedgehog It's more complex that simply finding the right accessor :)

Comment: Yes I want to make a property invisible and implement internal interface. i need the interface because few classes shall implement it and later i just cast to interface and i dont need to ask each time what type classes are since I only need the Obj property anyways from classes

Answer (score 0):

Your property still lacks a type. Even if you want to declare it as the explicit implementation of your interface member, you still need to specify the type.

```
class MyOwnerClass : iKey
{
    int id;

    int iKey.ID
    {
        get {return this.id;}
        set { this.id = value;}
    }
}
```

The "internal" access modifier given to the interface iKey will only make it not visible outside the namespace it's defined in. Nothing more and nothing less. Also, as some one pointed out, the better naming convention for an interface would be to use an adjective that describes the intended functionality set, with the prefix "I".

```
 internal class Poco
 {
   public string Str
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
}

internal interface ITest1
{
   Poco Obj
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
}

public class Foo : ITest1
{

   Poco Obj // missing access modifier
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
}
```

No access modifier is specified for Obj, which makes it private.

Comment: Interesting.. let me check

Comment: You cant have an access modifier. Thats the problem. Try it out. None of them is working. Not public or private or internal.

Comment: Interface member implementations must be either public or explicit. Also you can't specify any access modifier for explicitly implemented interfaces.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349276/compiler-says-i-am-not-implementing-my-interface-but-i-am

Comment: I dont need to. the interface shall stay internally. nobody may see it.